# Document Retention, Archving or Record Center Across Country Borders

Tags: sharepoint-server, records-management

Our organization is (or was) interested in the Records Center in SharePoint 2016.  Our single farm will be in the USA however, we have offices in other countries who's laws require "Records" content be retained in the Country of Origin.

How do other organizations handle this?  (i.e. do we have multiple farms each with a Record Center, store content on local country servers and just let SP Search to the work, 3rd part tool).  We have several (10-12) countries to consider.

Bismarck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement and limitation of SharePoint stretch farm, I would go with the small farm approach.

- Small farm within each country( How big the farm will be depend upon number of users and data)
- Create a Central Service farm,w here configure the Search service. All others farm will consume the search service from main farm.

But keep is mind not all services can be cross-farm supported. [Read this to understand more](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg441255.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#section7)